# Libgdx FrameBuffer Inadequate?

Tags: opengl, glsl, libgdx, framebuffer

Simply put, I want to create a ripple effect. How to achieve the ripple effect is not my issue. My problem is more technical in nature.

I currently have a sorts of ripple effect working, and how I achieve this is by using a FrameBuffer, writing everything I need to it, then turn on my Ripple Shader I create and viola.

This however is problematic, I'm capturing the entire screen when I only need a portion. I looked at the APIs and it appears there is no easy way to do this with FrameBuffers.

What now?

Comment: You're either rendering to the screen, or you're rendering to some other image. You can't do both at the same time. You can render "a portion" (by changing the viewport), but that would be *all* you render. The rest would not be rendered because it would be outside of the viewport area. Without more information on what you're actually trying to do, I can't help you.

Comment: I guess I have several questions. Is writing it to a frame buffer slower? Is there a good way to apply GLSL shaders to just a portion? I imagine I could use GL_fragCoords (or something like that) and test them against some uniform floats that would specify the area I want ripples in, but I'm not sure if this is the right way to go about this.

This is my first extrusion into shaders, and all I know is random bits that I've picked up through the web, so I apologize if i'm woefully uninformed.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use [`ScreenUtils`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ScreenUtils.html) instead of `FrameBuffer`.

> These methods can be used to get the entire screen content or a portion thereof.